# Multiple EXPLAIN in an Teradata SQL query

Tags: sql, teradata

Let us say we have 3 views: A,B and C.
A and B can be succesfully executed. C can not be succesfully executed.

I want to create an SQL query checking this which gives the output:

- View Verified
- A OK
- B OK
- C Not OK

In order to determine whether a view is runnable or not I prefer to run them according to: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM View_Name`

The reason is that e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) View_Name` is too slow.

Can I create the expected output using SQL? In that case how?
(I know that this can be solved using e.g. Python but I can't use it as part of this solution)

Comment: You can't get that result using a single query. This is usually done within a Stored Procedure where you open a cursor with all the View names and then run a `select 1 into declaredvariable from view where 1=0` against each view, while a Continue Handler catches any *object does not exist* error.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Paller describes in detail how to create a check like this in a stored procedure. As dnoeth states, this is only possible with a stored procedure.

Here is where Rob describes in a blog what his considerations and logic is:
https://robpaller.com/archive/2012/09/finding-broken-views-in-teradata/